# Cause of "Session Circular Kernel Context Logger failed to start error in Event Log?

Tags: windows-7, event-log

I'm running Windows 7 RTM 32-bit.

I'm getting the following error in my event log every second or so:

> Session "Circular Kernel Context
>   Logger" failed to start with the
>   following error: 0xC0000035

- Source: Kernel-EventTracing
- Level: Error
- User: SYSTEM
- OpCode: Start

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: I got this x50 from messing around with VM-ware and running virtual Windows 7 x64 inside Windows 7 x64. When this happens, I am forced to restart to get a stable system again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/2189-event-viewer-errors.html) which references the IPv6 protocol.  I disabled the protocol for my network adapter and now no longer get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find out what the Circular Kernel Context Logger is, I found this [article](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/w7itproperf/thread/1ad12734-3cd2-4733-936d-9c4071ecdb63) in which somebody says:

> Nothing to worry about, the system
>   repeatedly tries to start the logger
>   session until it succeeds. A temporary
>   failure to start mostly (but not
>   always) happens during a system state
>   transition from standby -> running.

If this doesn't fit your case, this other [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc238797%28PROT.10%29.aspx) states:

> The system state is a set of kernel
>   events generated by taking a snapshot
>   of the Circular Kernel Context Logger.

It's then possible (but improbable in my opinion) that the problem is related to system snap-shots. You might then verify in Control Panel / System / System protection, that everything seems well defined.

If none of the above ideas are useful, my only other idea would be to do a system repair.

Answer (score 0):

Session "Circular Kernel Context Logger" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035:

Windows version: Windows 7 64bit

If you are getting this message do as follows:

1. Start
2. click All Programs, and then click Accessories.
3. Right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
4. Type **powercfg -h on**, and then press **ENTER**.

Comment: It would be helpful to argument why disabling hibernation is a solution for this problem.

Comment: This command actually turns hibernation on if it is not.
Don't see how this is related to problem - on the system I have with the issue hibernation is already enabled.