# Event Viewer: Event ID 2 'Session "Circular Kernel Context Logger" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035'

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer

I've had 40 of these errors in the last 7 days.  Can anyone give an explanation of the error and what I might do to correct it?  I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.  As a possibly important aside I'm runnning a copy of Windows 7 that I've yet to activate (still trying to find the damn code before I cough up dough for the new one.)

Comment: Can you post yoru IPCONFIG /ALL ?

Comment: I want to make sure your subnet mask is correct: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293497

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/2189-event-viewer-errors.html#post391234

Comment: This seems to directly address the question.

Comment: Eww... a link only answer.  Here's the copy-pasta:
"The circular kernel context logger takes frequent snapshots of the system into a 100MB RAM file (not on disk). It is needed.
To fix the "fail to start" error, find the following file in the %windir%\panther\ folder:
setup.etl 
and rename it to
setup.old
It can stay in the \panther\ folder.
Reboot and all is done!"

Answer (score 3):

`0xC0000035` [stands for](http://source.winehq.org/source/include/ntstatus.h) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION, which means two [objects names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) collide.

First of all, before going further you should confirm that the logger is actually working:

1. Open Control Panel -> System -> Administrative Tools -> Performance Monitor.
2. Under Data Collector Sets -> Event Trace Sessions, verify that the Context Logger is running.

If it is running, there isn't really a problem; so you should just filter or ignore the error and move on.

If there is however a problem, you can [try some suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/40125/cause-of-session-circular-kernel-context-logger-failed-to-start-error-in-event-l) or analyze the prolem in more details:

1. Check what happens with the log files by using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and look at `C:\PerfLogs\Admin` and also pay noitce for any other failing operations when you restart the Context Logger yourself.
2. Use [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) and hook into the object name related functions or modules, this requires research...

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for a number of people:

ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release /all
they rebooted, but ipconfig /renew should work

They reported no errors after that.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/1ad12734-3cd2-4733-936d-9c4071ecdb63